# Compile Material 2 theme

Tags: angular, angular2-material

As per the material design documentation, if we want to create custom theme all we need to do is to include an `.scss` file as per the guidelines. I did the same but the scss files are not getting compiled. So do we need to compile the scss separately and then add it to the themes? or the compilation will be handled by angular2.

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: yes, is there an option to compile using cli?

Comment: You need to include the **theme.scss** in the styles section in angular-cli.json then is should compile.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!, Can you please write this as a solution as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the theme file under the **src** folder. Then it needs to be added to the **angular-cli.json** styles section as well.

```
  {
    ...
    "apps": [
      {
        ...
        "styles": [
          "theme.scss"
        ],      
      }
    ],
  ...
  }
```